# Lipschitz parametrization of a symmetric convex curve

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, convex-geometry, curves

Assume that $\gamma$ is a convex curve which is symmetric with respect to two orthogonal lines (the ellipse is such a curve).

1. I want to know if there exists a $(l,L)$-bi-Lipschitz mapping of the unit circle onto $\gamma$ such that $L=\mathbf{diam}(\gamma)/2$ and $l=\mathbf{dist}(\gamma,0)$, where $0$ is the center of $\gamma$.
2. Here is a weaker version of the above question: Does there exist a $L$-Lipschitz homeomorphism of the unit circle onto $\gamma$ such that $L=\mathbf{diam}(\gamma)/2$?

Comment: Tell us which maps did you try and what are the bound which you can prove.

Comment: @Anton. I guess that arc-length parametrization g is the best mapping for part. You can prove that $Lip(g)\le \pi/2 diam(γ)/2$, but this is not that I expect.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the convex hull $L_\varepsilon$ of the points $(\pm 1,0)$ and the $\varepsilon$-disc centered at the origin for small $\varepsilon>0$.

If there is a  $(\varepsilon,1)$-bi-Lipschitz map from the unit disc onto $L_\varepsilon$ then all the angles of curve bounding $L_\varepsilon$ has to be at least $\pi{\cdot}\varepsilon$ (see the sketch below).

On the other hand, $L_\varepsilon$ has two corners with angles about $2{\cdot} \varepsilon$.

---

*The sketch.* Assume $f$ maps the half-plane $H$ to the angle $A$ and has Lipschitz constants $\varepsilon$ and $1$, yet assume that $f(0)=0$ and $0$ is the tip of $A$.

Essentially we need to show that angle measure of $A$ is at least $\varepsilon{\cdot}\pi$.
Note that if $B_r(x)$ lies in $H$ then $B_{\varepsilon\cdot r}(f(x))$ lies in $A$. 
It follows that the image of an $\alpha$-angle in $H$ with tip at $0$ intersects unit circle along an arc of length $\varepsilon{\cdot}\alpha+o(\alpha)$.
Hence the result follows.

Comment: @Anton, I have made some revision of the previous question. 

Comment: @Anton: I didn't understand this argument indeed. How do you relate angles with bi-Lipschitz. Maybe it is not quasiconformal at the corrners.

Comment: @djoke, the answer is updated, you will see little more than you ask.

Comment: @Anton, Did you forget to put $\epsilon \alpha+o(\alpha)$. Remember that I am asking of  bi-Lipschitz mappings between curves (not between open domains).

Comment: sure, I will correct it. No I did not realized that you need  bi-Lipschitz mappings between curves; for the curves the question look much simpler...

Comment: @ Anton, I came back to the original question, since there is not a counterexample yet.

Answer (score 1):

For the Lipschitz-only part, the answer is yes. More generally, if $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are any two convex curves and $\beta$ fits inside an $L$-homothetic copy of $\alpha$, then there exist an $L$-Lipschitz map $f$ from $\alpha$ onto $\beta$.

Indeed, by rescaling we may assume that $\beta$ is inside $\alpha$, and $L=1$. In this case, let $f$ be the nearest-point projection to $\beta$, i.e. $f(x)$ is the point on $\beta$ nearest to $x$. It is easy to see that this map is well-defined in the outer region of $\beta$ and does not increase distances.

Comment: @Sergei I meant that the map should be a homeomorphism, otherwise the question is trivial. Your projection maybe is not onto? 

Comment: @djoke, it is not hard to perturb the map into a homeomorphism by making the Lipschitz constant little worse. 
On the other hand if you want to keep the constant then you can not do this --- square is an example. 

Comment: The square in not a counterexample. Namely, assume as we may that the square $|\gamma|=2\pi$. Then by using arc-length parametrization $f: S^1\to \gamma$ we obtain that $Lip(f)=\sqrt{2}{4}\pi$.

Comment: $Lip(f)=1/4 \sqrt{2} \pi$

Comment: @djoke: the map is onto, but indeed it fails to be injective if the target has corners. I overlooked that. It seems that it can be approximated by a homeomorphism with the same Lipschitz constant if the target is peicewise smooth. I am not sure about the case of infinitely many corners.
